# Keep latest/most recent row after accounting for duplicates

Tags: linux, file, unix, command-line

I have two files:

**old.csv**

```
id,a,b
X0,0,0
X1,1,1
X2,2,2
```

**new.csv**

```
id,a,b
X0,0,1
X2,2,2
X3,3,3
X4,4,4
X5,5,5
X6,6,6
X7,7,7
```

Where `id` is a unique identifier within each file.

My goal is twofold: 1) to find any rows in `old.csv` that have changed, and append any "new" rows from `new.csv`; 2) to append the result from 1) to the existing `old.csv` file, while keeping only the most recent (last/lower in the file) occurrence of each unique `id` value.

I have accomplished 1):

```
$ diff -u old.csv new.csv | grep '^+[^+]' | sed 's/^+//' > results.csv
$ cat results.csv
X0,0,1
X3,3,3
X4,4,4
X5,5,5
X6,6,6
X7,7,7
```

This is great - it gives me X0 (which has changed), leaves out X1 and X2 (which haven't changed), and appends the "new" lines.

I have also accomplished part of 2):

```
$ cat results.csv >> old.csv
$ cat old.csv
id,a,b
X0,0,0
X1,1,1
X2,2,2
X0,0,1
X3,3,3
X4,4,4
X5,5,5
X6,6,6
X7,7,7
```

But the first instance of X0 is still there... I would like only to keep the most recent instances, so row 5 in the `old.csv` file. My desired result would look like this:

```
id,a,b
X1,1,1
X2,2,2
X0,0,1
X3,3,3
X4,4,4
X5,5,5
X6,6,6
X7,7,7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F, '
    NR  == 1 {print} 
    FNR == 1 {next} 
             {data[$1] = $0} 
    END      {for (id in data) print data[id]}
' old.csv new.csv
```

To save back to old.csv do one of:

```
awk ... old.csv new.csv > old.csv.new && mv old.csv.new old.csv
```

or use [`sponge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sponge.1.html) from the moreutils package

```
awk ... old.csv new.csv | sponge old.csv
```